# Heroku excel file nodejs

Tags: node.js, email, xlsx

I am trying to build an excel file from my website data and then email it to a set (admin) email address using nodejs.

The site ie hosted on Heroku on the Hobby dyno.

When testing the functionality on my local, it works fine but on the actual live environment it won't work. Is it possible to build an excel file from a Heroku server?

I used the exceljs and emailjs packages and built the file. It works perfectly on my local. But when pushing the code to the heroku site no email is sent with the file attached. Is this possible from the Heroku server? Could it possibly work when using a csv file instead of a xlsx file?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This question would greatly benfit from adding some code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.